# IP tables forwarding with initial delay

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a situation where I would like to forward traffic on a machine to another IP, but with an initial connection delay of x seconds. More specifically, I have a rule like

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -d 1.1.1.1  -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I want that rule to take effect immediately, but I *also* want to delay actually sending traffic to 1.1.1.1 for x seconds, so clients would see a delay of up to x seconds in getting a response from 1.1.1.1, but *only* initially. Is there a way to achieve this with iptables (or any other unix networking tools)?

Comment: Is the delay on the connect (time until the first syn is allowed), or after the handshake (syn, syn+ack, ack) for some amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt iptables has this kind of functionality, but TCP proxy software often has features to simulate access to servers through slow/congested networks or other impairments.

I did a quick Google search and saw that the often-used [Squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) can simulate slow networks but doesn't offer the initial delay you asked for.

Other results in the search were [Toxiproxy](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy) and [delaying-proxy](https://github.com/ruwanta/delaying-proxy) which do offer delays, but there are likely more than those two.  My search terms were `tcp` `proxy` `delay` - try your own search and see if there's one that meets your needs.

Comment: Yeah, on continued Googling I think the easily-accessible `tc` command could be used to introduce the temporary connect latency I need here...