# How to make network slow for firefox but not curl?

Tags: networking

Using the terminal I'd like to run a command that makes firefox become slow (as in 30+ seconds per request) or lose all traffic. However I don't want it to be system wide. I'll be running curl commands and I want those to stay full speed.

Comment: You could run Firefox in its own network namespace and apply tc there

Comment: Firefox can be configured to use a proxy, so it might not be necessary to run firefox in a namespace to make it use tc.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I never used tc. Is there a simple 1 liner I can use? Judging by google and the man pages it doesn't look simple?

Comment: @SottoVoce Is there a simple proxy I can use?

Comment: @Stan there's the `tc` program already mentioned.  A while ago I posted proxy suggestions to another question and they could possibly meet your needs:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709157/531636

Answer (score 0):

You could use `trickle`, a lightweight userspace bandwidth shaper.

Example from the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/trickle/trickle.1.en.html):

```
trickle -u 10 -d 20 ncftp
```

Launch `ncftp` limiting its upload capacity to 10 KB/s, and download capacity at 20 KB/s.